# onclick event triggers infinitely

Tags: javascript

I am running into an infinite event trigger loop in my Javascript code when I click on element #add-channel. I am wondering if this code below looks sound, it might be due to my html code? Not sure if that can trigger an infinite loop here.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // connect to websocket
  var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
  //load username into profile name on document load
  document.querySelector('#profile-name').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('name');
  // hide the modal for chatroom creation
  var modal1 = document.getElementById("myModal1");
  modal1.style.display = "none";
  // prompt user for new name if local name is null
  if (localStorage.getItem('name') === null){
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
    modal.style.display = "block";
    // on submit, store name into local storage and set the current name
    document.querySelector('#form').onsubmit = function() {
      modal.style.display = "none";
      let name = localStorage.getItem('name');
      name = document.querySelector('#name').value;
      document.querySelector('#profile-name').innerHTML = name;
      localStorage.setItem('name', name);
    };
  };

  // display clear button only when user has entered a display name
    var button = document.getElementById("settings");
    if (localStorage.getItem('name') === null) {
      button.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      button.style.display = "block";
    }

  // This guy right here runs infinite times...
  document.querySelector('#add-channel').onclick = () => {
      // pop up modal
      modal1.style.display = "block";
      console.log("I like to run infinite times")
    };
  });
```

This doesn't happen in Edge browser but it does in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: If you want a good answer to this question, please provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) rather than pasting in a bunch of unreadable code. This makes a little bit more work for you, but others will be much more motivated to help you out if they can easily see what is going on.

Comment: ok thank you, I will try this out.

Comment: @UnsolvedCypher, I finally trimmed it down.

Comment: Do you have some HTML with that ?

Comment: @SScotti, I can't really post it up there for edit..But I see this in the console when this repeat occurs. codepen thing

<script src='//production-assets.codepen.io/assets/common/stopExecutionOnTimeout-b2a7b3fe212eaa732349046d8416e00a9dec26eb7fd347590fbced3ab38af52e.js'></script><script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'></script>

Comment: <div id="bottom-bar">
   <button id="add-channel"><i class="fa fa-user-plus fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span>Add channel</span></button>
   <button id="settings"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span>Log Out</span></button>
  </div>
 </div>

This is the message that it sends

http://production-assets.codepen.io/assets/editor/live/console_runner-079c09a0e3b9ff743e39ee2d5637b9216b3545af0de366d4b9aad9dc87e26bfd.js

Answer (score 0):

So I deleted that script file and it fixed the problem for now. I am still unsure why this happens as someone who is just using a Bootstrap template. Making me feel uncomfortable coding here for sure. It has not affected the performance of the template so far.